# VB.net LINQ group by multiple fields

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to LINQ. I have a list (of xRef) in vb.net code.

```
dim xRefList as List (Of String)
```

Class xRef has 5 public properties, in summary:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal fSource_ As String, ByVal fSourceConfig_ As String, ByVal fTarget_ As 

String, ByVal fTargetConfig_ As String, ByVal isFSuppressed_ As Short)
         fSource = fSource_
         fSourceCfg = fSourceConfig_
         fTarget = fTarget_
         fTargetConfig = fTargetConfig_
         isFSuppressed = isFSuppressed_
End Sub
```

I'd like to group by and get count of:

```
a) fsource and ftarget (similar to SQL group by fsource,ftarget,count(fsource))
b) fsource,fSourceCfg ,ftarget,fTargetConfig and count isFSuppressed
```

I am looking at my list to have up to hundreds of items. I am not talking about very large lists.

Comment: Something similar to: `xRefList.GroupBy(Function(o) New With {Key .Source = o.fSource, Key .Target = o.fTarget})` and you can count the groups.

Comment: Did you search first?  There are [13 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+%5Blinq%5D+group+by+multiple+fields) that are about the same general topic (and even more if you include all .Net languages).  If none of these answer your question, then you may want to explain why in order to get better answers.

Comment: Should that first line be a `List(Of xRef)`, or is it really strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Group by with multiple properties in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308851/linq-group-by-with-multiple-properties-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thank you all, I did search buy found mainly group by single field. I will look into LINQ Group by with multiple properties in VB.Net. I guess I missed this one.